# OpenSSL not found during ./configure

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, configure

I'm trying to make one bitcoin-like daemon on my Ubuntu 14.04.3.
When I hit `./configure`:

```
checking for SSL... no
configure: error: openssl  not found.
```

but

```
# apt-get install libssl-dev linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.13.0-61-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I googled the error message but I haven't any idea what to do. I successfully maked exactly that one daemon on my other Ubuntu 14.04 so the sources and configuration scripts are good.

UPD1.
Installing openssl didn't help:

```
# apt-get install openssl
..
openssl is already the newest version.
..
```

I've checked config.log and there're nothing about openssl at the end - `HAVE_WORKING_BOOST_SLEEP_FOR` refers to `checking for dynamic linked boost test... yes` - last successful line from `./configure` output:

```
# tail config.log
#define HAVE_BOOST /**/
#define HAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM /**/
#define HAVE_BOOST_FILESYSTEM /**/
#define HAVE_BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS /**/
#define HAVE_BOOST_THREAD /**/
#define HAVE_BOOST_CHRONO /**/
#define HAVE_BOOST_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK /**/
#define HAVE_WORKING_BOOST_SLEEP_FOR 1

configure: exit 1
```

UPD2. I've found that in log, quite far from the end:

```
configure:25626: checking for SSL
configure:25633: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "libssl"
Package libssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libssl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libssl' found
configure:25636: $? = 1
configure:25650: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "libssl"
Package libssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libssl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libssl' found
configure:25653: $? = 1
configure:25667: result: no
No package 'libssl' found
configure:25683: error: openssl  not found.
```

Comment: [libssl-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl-dev) is not [openssl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openssl). Try installing the latter. If that doesn't help, then check `config.log` for the exact command that's failing (it will be right near the end) and [edit] your question to include it, and we can suggest what you are missing.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: But autoconf output isn't Debian package names, either… It's more likely that it refers to _pkg-config_ packages (and libssl-dev does include openssl.pc).

Comment: Updated. Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: Does the file `/usr/lib/<arch>/pkgconfig/libssl.pc` exist?

Comment: What is <arch>? `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/; /usr/share/pkgconfig/; /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/` don't contain `libssl.pc`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` didn't contain the right path for that `openssl.pc` file needed for pkg-config utility. I did `find / -name 'openssl.pc'` and found it in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/`. That path was also used by my other ubuntu to `./configure`.

**So I ran `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/" ./configure`  and that did the trick!**

Other thing, there is another `openssl.pc` in my `/usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig/` but when I tried to use it, the following `make` command hangs with different errors (like unknown reference to function, etc.).

Comment: Same here, openssl was installed using brew, and I was installing libevent on macos by building it.

Answer (score 16):

You will find a package name `libssl-dev` in Synaptic Package Manager (Ubuntu 16.04) and after you install `libssl-dev`, everything will be solved. by the way, `libssl1.0.0` don't works. You'd better install `libssl-dev` and  `libssl1.0.0` at same time.

by the way, I don't think the following solution is works:   'pkg-config' is in your PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via: R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'

Comment: I was trying to run a Crystal Lang http server and got the error "Package libssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libssl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libssl' found
". Installing libssl-dev solved the problem.